Bounded homomorphism
Let $H,K$ be Hilbert spaces and $X,Y$ be subsets of $\mathcal{B}(H,K)$ and $\mathcal{B}(K,H),$ respectively. By $[Y X]$ we denote the w*-closure of the linear span of the set consisting of operators $y x,$ where $y\in Y$ and $x\in X.$
Definition: A linear subspace $M$ of $\mathcal{B}(H,K)$ is called a TRO if $m\ n^*\ k\in M$ for all $m,n,k\in M.$
(For more details check Section 8.3 in Blecher-Le Merdy).
Let $M\subseteq \mathcal{B}(H,K)$ be a TRO and let $L$ be a Hilbert space. Suppose that $u\colon [M^* M]\to \mathcal{B}(L)$ is a w*-continuous and bounded homomorphism.
Can you define a w*-continuous and bounded homomorphism $\tilde{u}\colon [M M^*]\to \mathcal{B}(L)$?
Comment: Since $M$ is a TRO we can easily see that $[M^* M]$ and $[M M^*]$ are von Neumann algebras.

If all Hilbert spaces are assumed separable infinite-dimensional, then of course there is such a homomorphism, since any separably acting von Neumann algebra embeds into $\mathcal{B}(L)$ for a separable infinite-dimensional $L$. But I don’t see any reason why there should be a homomorphism that’s naturally connected to $u$. After all, there’s not much connection between $[M^\ast M]$ and $[MM^\ast]$ in general.

Thank you for your answer.

There is a connection, the so-called Morita equivalence in the sense of Rieffel.

That’s true. I suppose there are some cases in which you can define $\tilde{u}$, now that I have thought about this more. For example, assuming all Hilbert spaces involved are infinite-dimensional and separable, if $[M^\ast M]$ is a type III factor isomorphic to its opposite algebra and $u$ is a $\ast$-homomorphism, then as a right-$[M^\ast M]$-module, $L$ and $M$ have to be isomorphic, which does induce a left action of $[MM^\ast]$. Similarly if $[M^\ast M]$ is a finite factor isomorphic to its opposite and the index of $L$ is infinite.
